# USB stick modem stopped connecting after upgrade to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, usb, modem

my USB stick modem does not connect after upgrading to 11.10. It worked ok on 11.04. It is found now (the connection called "O2 Default 1" in my case is active), however it does not connect automatically as it used to do and when I try to connect it manually it shows "Home network selected" or something for a second and than it disconnects (and when trying to connect again, it says "Modem network disconnected" immediately).
Thanks for your help, it is needed(-:

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with my rogers nokia usb stick, I got mine working by disabling the ubuntu control over WLAN and downloading the linux driver from the nokia website, it did give me some warnings when installing the driver but it works.